# How to return a connection from a callback in node

Tags: node.js, database, async-await

I want to create a db.js file that all my other files can use. The idea is that the connection created in this db.js file can be reused without reconnecting to database everytime i make a call.

db.js

```
var nodeq = require("node-q");
var connection;

nodeq.connect({host: "192.168.1.1", port: 5000}, function(err, con) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection = con;
    console.log("KDB connected");
  });

module.exports=connection;
```

I want to do something like above(doesnt work) But the idea is in my app.js i will set

```
var db = require("./db")
```

and it will return the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `.connect()` call in a promise and return this promise from your module, e.g.

```
const nodeq = require("node-q");

module.exports = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
  nodeq.connect({host: "192.168.1.1", port: 5000}, function(err, con) {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    console.log("KDB connected");
    resolve(con);
  });
});
```

Then in your caller you can await this promise (still needs error handling, but should give you a start):

```
const dbConnection = await require("./db");
```

or you do:

```
const dbConnPromise = require("./db");
//... then somewhere in your code where you need the db-connection, you can do:

async function doDbStuff() {
   const db = dbConnPromise();
   const result = await db.query(...);
}
```

Comment: everytime i do this though wont it create a new connection?

Comment: Nope, modules are cached. So the `connect`-call will only be executed for the first require.

Comment: Don't forget to accept if it works for you, please.